# I have django form that is initialized with request, args and kwargs, now I want to create formset from it, how to do it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
class SpecialDateHJRTableEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HJRTableEntry
        fields = ['job_template', 'date']
        widgets = {'is_special_date': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'value': True}),'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})}

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is my form, now I want to create a formset for this form, how to do it?

Solution to the above issue.